# How can I see the validation results while in a controller's action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an update action in a controller that performs an UpdateModel.  Before I pass the data back to the view I want to log the properties that failed to validate.

I expected the dictionary where the errors are stored to be in the ModelState (since the method AddModelError() is there) but this doesn't seem to be the case.  How can I access this dictionary while still in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Controller:

```
 foreach (ModelState state in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
        foreach (ModelError error in state.Errors)
          MyLog(error.ErrorMessage);
```

Comment: @Andrey:  thanks! this looks good... as soon as I can test it out I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ok. For me it works. I'm using it in helper for localization of messages comming from validator.